# MS access query error :Syntax error(missing operator)

Tags: sql, ms-access

I am trying to run a query on MS Access I am a newbie in it. I have to find difference of two dates then find count of those who have diff > 10.I am using the `datediff`

Function for the same

```
SELECT  count(Admission No.)
From Admissions
where DATEDIFF(DAY, Admission Date, Discharge Date) >10
```

Where i am going wronmg i am getting a syntax  error

Answer (score 1):

Try to encapsulate fields name in square brackets

```
SELECT  count([Admission No.])
 From Admissions
 where DATEDIFF(DAY, [Admission Date], [Discharge Date]) >10
```